# simple Mavericks GUI

Tags: macos, user-interface, shoes

I need some help with a simple GUI in mavericks. Right now I am trying to do it in shoes, but I am open to something else. My basic needs are a GUI with a background image, 3 graphic buttons with text under them. I need 1 of the buttons to reboot the computer, and the other 2 will copy a file from one location and paste it in another directory. It also needs to over write the existing file with no confirmation, or delete it before it pastes the copied one.

In shoes I have the background set, and 2 graphic buttons, but don't know how to make it copy and paste a file when clicked. Thank for the help.

Here is my code, I know it is very ugly but I am still learning it and once I get it to work I was going to start cleaning it up...

```
Shoes.app(title: "OS Boost Selector", width: 650, heigth: 400 ) do    
background "background.png"
flow left: 100, top: 100 do
button= image "device_ntfs.png" do
FileUtils.cp_r ‘/Volumes/Mavericks/Extra/Windows 7/org.chameleon.Boot.plist', ‘/Volumes/Mavericks/Extra/org.chameleon.Boot.plist', :remove_destination => true 
end
end
stack left: 110, top: 265 do
para "Windows 7", font: "Trebuchet MS", size: 20, stroke: white
end

flow left: 400, top: 100 do
button= image "device_hfsplus_mav.png" do
FileUtils.cp_r ‘/Volumes/Mavericks/Extra/Mavericks/org.chameleon.Boot.plist', ‘/Volumes/Mavericks/Extra/org.chameleon.Boot.plist', :remove_destination => true
end
end
flow left: -100, top: 250 do
buttom= image "logo.png" do
#system(“sudo shutdown -r now”)
end
end
stack left: 295, top: 450 do
para "(Reboot)", font: "Trebuchet MS", size: 16, stroke: white
end
stack left: 415, top: 265 do
para "Mavericks", font: "Trebuchet MS", size: 20, stroke: white
end
end
```

Comment: Shoes? Have you got a link for that? How does your code look? Can you execute a shell script from this `shoes` thing? If so, it is pretty easy to copy a file in `bash`, you just do `cp fileA /some/where/else/newFile`

Comment: http://shoesrb.com shoes is for ruby, though I have never used ruby before. I am not sure if I can use normal ruby code or not. If so I don't know how to do that yet either. I have never written any code in Mac only windows. I can copy and paste my code I have too if it will help thx

Comment: Ok I figured out how to copy and paste the files using FileUtils.cp However I am not sure how to overwrite the file that already exists in the location.

Comment: ok i got that with  FileUtils.cp_r and :remove_destination => true ) now the only thing i have left to figure out is how to reboot the system. anyone know how to do that with ruby and mavericks? thanks

Comment: You can use `system("sudo shutdown -r now")`

Comment: You will need to add your username to the `/etc/sudoers` file to do this without a password. Type `man sudoers` for details.

Comment: Thanks. I have a few more problems now though. 1st I wrote the code in windows ruby using the FileUtils.cp_r and it worked great when I switched back to mac, it throws an error on the _r. Also if I comment that stuff out it throws an error on the "m" in the system("sudo shutdown -r now") any ideas what i need to do to fix this?  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileUtils.cp_r("/Volumes/Mavericks/Extra/Windows 7/org.chameleon.Boot.plist", "/Volumes/Mavericks/Extra/org.chameleon.Boot.plist", :remove_destination => true)

That is what I needed for the copy and overwrite the file.

This is what I did to get the mac to reboot
`open -a reboot'

when I press the reboot button in my gui it opens reboot app in applications which is an app saved from automator that runs the following applescript:

ignoring application responses
tell application "Finder"
restart
end tell
end ignoring

This works exactly now like I was wanting. thanks for all the help and patience!

Comment: Now I would like to get the reboot working. anymore help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try using the full path like this: `sudo /sbin/shutdown -r now`

Comment: `open -a Automator` opens Automator, i got terminal to open from ruby, but not sure how to make ruby send the commands to terminal to reboot.

Comment: system("sudo /sbin/shutdown -r now");

Comment: Thanks that fixed the error, but it does not appear that it does anything in my code. does it have to be an from terminal?

Comment: I am at a loss. I can't seem to get this to reboot the computer. I guess I could always just go click on the the reboot... is there a way to force reboot even if something is open? I ask because I connect to the computer remotely and as soon as I click reboot I lose connection to the computer but sometimes when I get home it is still waiting to reboot because a window has popped up asking if I am sure I want to go ahead and reboot (or something like that)

Comment: it looks like if I could send keys Ctrl+Cmd+Eject that I could restart that way, but I can not figure out how to send keystrokes.

Comment: Ok I have an idea though I am not sure if it will work or how to do it. can I amke a workflow in automator, then have shoes open that (since I can open apps) and have it auto run the workflow when it is opened? if so it looks like I could do my keystrokes in automator. is this correct? would this work? thanks?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the information for modifying `/etc/sudoers` so your user (i.e. you) can do sysadmin stuff by prefixing commands with `sudo` and at the same time not having to provide a password. First, you need to find your username, using `id` like this:

```
id
uid=502(mark) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff), ...
```

so my user id is 'mark', and I need to put that in `/etc/sudoers`, so I do:

```
sudo visudo
```

and use the editor to go down to this bit below and add myself (mark) as allowed to do anything I like on any host without needing a password every time - ooh feel the power:

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
mark    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Now, I can run the shutdown/reboot command without needing a password:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did that already though. My problem seems to be in my ruby code.

Comment: ok i tried to delete the post don't know if it worked or not. sorry if I posted the code wrong...

Comment: FileUtils.cp_r("{$/Volumes/Mavericks/Extra/Windows 7/org.chameleon.Boot.plist}/.", "{$/Volumes/Mavericks/Extra/org.chameleon.Boot.plist}", :remove_destination => true) This does not give me an error though it also does not copy the file. it appears to be doing nothing. I think maybe it is in how the location of the file is typed but I am not sure.